# Per-Class singleton, prevent additional instances

Tags: java, singleton

How can I define three classes A,B,C so that each one can only ever be instantiated once. In other words, if a single `A` has already been instantiated, no more may be created. But creating a `B` should be fine (as long as no other `B` was created first).

```
class A{
}

class B extends A{
}

class C extends B{
}
```

Produce:

```
A a1 = new A(); //Should work fine

A a2 = new A(); // Should throw an error if one instance is already created

B b1 = new B(); // Should work fine despite A instance is there or not

B b2 = new B(); // Should throw an error

C c1 = new C(); // Should work fine despite B instance is there or not

C c2 = new C(); // Should throw an error
```

Comment: Nice list... Are you sure everything is correct? Could you ask anything, please?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you are asking.  Could you add some context around what you'd like to achieve and why you currently can't?

Comment: Why a2, b2 and c2 should throw errors? Why singleton tag is on the tags of the question?

Comment: @IoannisBarakos I think this is kind of a reverse question where OP wants to get the implementation that leads to the results posted.

Comment: How _singleton_ notion is connected to the code?

Comment: Hi @Geet Mittal, I think you should specify your question and show some of your code that don't work. Don't expect a full solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a bad idea to do something like that, as it's very "magic-y" to deny construction of an object just because another one was already created, but it's possible:

```
public class A {
  private static final Set<Class<?>> INSTANTIATED_CLASSES = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

  public A() {
    if (!INSTANTIATED_CLASSES.add(this.getClass())) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Oh no! " + this.getClass() + " was already instantiated once!");
    }
  }
}
```

This will ensure that you can only ever construct exactly on instance of `A` or any of its sub-classes.

Note that a major drawback of global state like this is that it'll become exceedingly different to test your code, if you can't just instantiate objects at will.